# Custom module menu item declaration leads to error 404

Tags: 7, routes

```
function eventi_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['eventi/book/%/'] = array(
    'title' => 'Book',
    'page callback' => 'eventi_book',
    'access arguments' => array('allow booking'),
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  $items['eventi/book_waits/%/'] = array(
    'title' => 'Book Waits',
    'page callback' => 'eventi_book',
    'access arguments' => array('allow booking'),
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  $items['eventi/unbook/%/'] = array(
    'title' => 'Unbook',
    'page callback' => 'eventi_unbook',
    'access arguments' => array('allow booking'),
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items;
}

function eventi_book($nid) {
  echo 'something';
}
```

All worked OK, but suddenly, when I visit (for example) http://example.com/eventi/book/201, I get an error 404. I cleared the cache, but I keep to get the same error. Do you have any clue why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ending slash in the paths.

```
function eventi_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['eventi/book/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Book',
    'page callback' => 'eventi_book',
    'access arguments' => array('allow booking'),
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  $items['eventi/book_waits/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Book Waits',
    'page callback' => 'eventi_book',
    'access arguments' => array('allow booking'),
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  $items['eventi/unbook/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Unbook',
    'page callback' => 'eventi_unbook',
    'access arguments' => array('allow booking'),
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that trailing slash on the path is throwing you

```
$items['eventi/book/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Book',
  'page callback' => 'eventi_book',
  'access arguments' => array('allow booking'),
  'page arguments' => array(2),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
);
```

Also, if you use `%node` for the variable in the path, the menu router will call `node_load()` on the given `nid` from the path and you'll get the full `$node` object in your callback function, like so:

```
$items['eventi/book/%node'] = array(
  'title' => 'Book',
  'page callback' => 'eventi_book',
  'access arguments' => array('allow booking'),
  'page arguments' => array(2),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
);

// ...and so on, until...

function eventi_book($node) {
   return $node->title;
}
```

Also note that your callback function should return a value, not echo it.

Comment: A menu callback can print a value: see what is done from [node_feed()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_feed/6), which is the menu callback for the path rss.xml, and which prints its output. The difference between printing the result, and returning a string is that in the latter case [index.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/index.php/6/source) passes the string, as `$return`, to `theme('page', $return)`. Another difference is that when the menu callback returns a string, that string is cached by Drupal for anonymous users.